# open saveas dialog in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

i am trying to let a user save an xml file to a location of his choice. Do you have any examples of how to write a saveas location for an asp.net mvc 2 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Content-Disposition header and specify the `attachment` property which will prompt the user with a Save As dialog box:

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var cd = new ContentDisposition
    {
        FileName = "foo.xml",
        Inline = false
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    var xml = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("<root>some content</root>");
    return File(xml, "text/xml");
}
```